# How to do character comparison in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my code

```
#! /bin/bash
read var
if [ $var="Y" -o $var="y" ]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

I want to print YES if the user presses y or Y, otherwise I want to print NO. Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: aren't you getting any error messages? You need to leave spaces around the `=` signs. Also, you can do this as `case "$var" in [Yy]* ) echo yes ;; * ) echo no ;; esac`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This is a question from hackerrank website, you little cheater :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, your Condition is wrong. Quote your variables and leave spaces between operators (like shellter wrote). So it should look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
read var
if  [ "$var" = "Y" ] || [ "$var" = "y" ]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

*Edit*: for POSIX ccompatibility

- Replaced `==` with `=` - see comments
- Replaced `-o` syntax with `||` syntax - see comments

Comment: Oh thanks, I did add spaces. But it worked even without quoting $var.

Comment: Quoting variables in comparison is more or less best practice It has to do with the possibility of variables not being set, which results in syntax error. Yes, you probably don't need it in your case. But you should. :)

Comment: @lufork Unquoted variables can cause trouble if they're blank, or contain spaces or some wildcards. Try without quotes with `var` blank, or set to "yes I guess" or "*". Putting variable references in double-quotes is almost always a good idea, just to avoid weird results in case the variables contain anything unexpected.

Comment: Isn't `-o` in `[ ]` discouraged and should be replaced by `[ ] || [ ]`? See here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: Also, `==` is a bashism here.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Indeed, it is a Bashism. `=` is encouraged if you want compatibility with another POSIX compatible shell.

Comment: The only reason to use `==` inside `[` is if you know that you are using `bash`, in which case you should be using `[[ $var = [yY] ]]` instead.

Answer (score 5):

With Bash, you can also use regular expression in your test with the `=~` operator:

```
read var
[[ "$var" =~ [Yy] ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"
```

Or as Benjamin W. mentionned, simply use character range with the `==` operator:

```
read var
[[ "$var" == [Yy] ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"
```

Comment: In this case, you don't even need regular expressions - shell patterns are enough: `[[ $var == [Yy] ]]`

Comment: Note that the `=~` operator is only available in `[[ ]]` (bash's improved conditional expression), not in `[ ]` (ye olde standard `test` command). See [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Answer (score 1):

There is minor syntax error in your code.

> Correction : There should be a white space between operators and variables

```
read var

if [ $var = "Y" -o $var = "y" ]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Try the above bash script.

Hope it would work fine.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

If all you require is a upper/lowercase comparison, use the `,,` operator on the variable being compared ( note the `${var,,}` ):

```
#!/bin/bash
read var
if [ ${var,,} = "y" ]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

or more succinctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
read var
[ ${var,,} = 'y' ] && echo 'YES' || echo 'NO'
```

or the way I might actually do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
read var
[[ "${var,,}" == 'y' ]] && echo 'YES' || echo 'NO'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that I tried.

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "Are you Sure?(Y/N) " answer
if [ "$answer" = "y" ] || [ "$answer" = "Y" ]; then
  echo "Do your stuff."
else
  echo "Do your other stuff"
fi
```

Add whitespace around '=' and your code will run fine.

```
#! /bin/bash
read var
if [ $var = "Y" -o $var = "y" ]
then
  echo "YES"
else
  echo "NO"
fi
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince be otherwise please explain how this works and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Shebang line is not there. And else statement is not there.  I just put the code I tested assuming other required part will be understood by the author of the question. Anyway I have updated the answer.

Comment: Refresh please.

Comment: Still no explanation. Still giving the impression that you mistake StackOverflow for a platform for giving away your programming work for free, without really trying to help other people understand their problems. Even your first comment does not explain anything, just states that you assume others to understand without explanation. Please explain how it works and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
#! /bin/bash
read var
echo -e "YES\nNO\n" | grep -i $var
```